# Output Results from an SQL query in a particular fashion for Display in Pie Chart

Tags: c#, sql-server, charts, datatable

Apologies for the vague question as I am unsure how to word it exactly.

I have the following query which counts number of student have paid, yet to pay and partially paid their fee's for a particular year.

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
            (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
             FROM fee_payments
             WHERE (fee_remaining = 0)) AS Fully_Paid,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
             FROM fee_payments AS fee_payments_3
             WHERE (fee_remaining = fee_required)) AS Unpaid,
            (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1
             FROM fee_payments AS fee_payments_2
             WHERE (fee_remaining > 0)
               AND (fee_remaining <> fee_required)) AS Partially_Paid
        FROM 
            fee_payments AS fee_payments_1
```

The output displays as

```
Fully_Paid | Unpaid | Partially_Paid
-------------------------------------
     8     |   1    |       5
```

I have the following C# for my Pie Chart

```
public partial class feestatistics: System.Web.UI.Page {
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  //populate ddl
  if (!IsPostBack) {
   string query = "SELECT year_id, year_title FROM year";
   DataTable dt = GetData(query);
   ddlyear.DataSource = dt;
   ddlyear.DataTextField = "year_title";
   ddlyear.DataValueField = "year_id";
   ddlyear.DataBind();
   ddlyear.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Select", ""));
  }

 }

 protected void ddlyear_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Chart1.Visible = ddlyear.SelectedValue != "";
  string query = string.Format("SELECT DISTINCT (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM fee_payments WHERE (fee_remaining = 0) AND (year = '{0}')) AS Fully_Paid, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM fee_payments WHERE (fee_remaining = fee_required) AND (year ='{0}')) AS Unpaid, (SELECT COUNT(*) AS Expr1 FROM fee_payments WHERE (fee_remaining > 0) AND (year = '{0}') AND (fee_remaining <> fee_required)) AS Partially_Paid FROM fee_payments AS fee_payments_1", ddlyear.SelectedValue);
  DataTable dt = GetData(query);
  string[] x = new string[dt.Rows.Count];
  int[] y = new int[dt.Rows.Count];
  for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++) {
   x[i] = dt.Rows[i][0].ToString();
   y[i] = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i][1]);
  }
  Chart1.Series[0].Points.DataBindXY(x, y);
  //Chart1.Series[0].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
  Chart1.ChartAreas["ChartArea1"].Area3DStyle.Enable3D = true;
  Chart1.Legends[0].Enabled = true;


 }

 private static DataTable GetData(string query) {
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(query);
  String constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
  SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr);
  SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
  cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
  cmd.Connection = con;
  sda.SelectCommand = cmd;
  sda.Fill(dt);
  return dt;
 }
}
```

However, my pie chart is displaying as follows
[image]

This is the desired pie chart I wish to achieve, how would I go about doing this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

[image]

Comment: You're making it much harder than it should be.... Create a pie chart first, using just some sample data you can input manually, understand how the pie chart works and THEN, attempt to do the same using data pulled from the database.

Comment: Did you check on the number of rows in your datatable?

Answer (score 0):

In your chart variable, you are gonna need to add the next code to get you want.

```
chartName.Series[serieName].XValueMember = columnName;
chartName.Series[serieName].YValueMembers = value;
chartName.Series[serieName].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
```

For example, in your case, it's gonna looks like:

```
DataTable dt = GetData(query);
Chart1.DataSource = dt;
Chart1.Series.Add("fee");
Chart1.Series["fee"].ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
Chart1.Series["fee"].XValueMember = "state";
Chart1.Series["fee"].YValueMembers = "percent";
Chart1.Series["fee"].IsValueShownAsLabel = true;
Chart1.DataBind();
```

Note: Notice the line that have been set with a ChartType, it is basically to handle different charts types with similar data to be shown.
Regards and blessings.